Building a forest from a list of "tree paths"
Starting from a list of "tree paths", for example:
[["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "b", "e"], ["f", "g"]]

I would like to build a forest ([Tree]):
a
|_ b
  |_ c
  |_ e
f
|_ g

This is my attempt so far. I have been constructing the building blocks in order to assemble the final solution:
module Main where

import Data.Tree

insertPath :: Eq a => [a] -> [Tree a] -> [Tree a]
insertPath [] ts = ts
insertPath (y:ys) [] = Node y [] : []
insertPath (y:ys) ((Node x ts):ts')
    | y /= x = Node x ts : insertPath ys ts'
    | otherwise = Node x (insertSubTrees ys ts) : insertPath ys ts'

insertSubTrees :: Eq a => [a] -> [Tree a] -> [Tree a]
insertSubTrees [] ts = ts
insertSubTrees (y:ys) [] = insertSubTrees ys [Node y []]
insertSubTrees (y:ys) (t:ts) = undefined

My questions are:

Should I define functions over a Tree or a list of Tree ?
Is my approach sensible ? What are other alternatives ?
How can I develop a buildForest :: Eq a => [a] -> [Tree a] -> [Tree a] function ?


The type of buildForest perhaps should use [[a]] instead of [a]. If so, consider using a fold operation. foldr should work, I guess.

Further, I'd doubly check the ys in | y /= x = Node x ts : insertPath ys ts'. It looks wrong to me right now.

Thank you very much, @chi. Indeed, I wanted [[a]]. I will look into your suggestions.

Thank you for the insight, @chi. You were right, I should change that to insertPath (y:ys) ts'. In that line, y is not equal to x, so I shouldn't remove it from the recursive call. Any suggestion about insertSubTrees ? Or perhaps that function is not even necessary ?

Feel free to edit your question to include those changes. It looks like insertSubTrees is the same as insertPath. Both insert a path in a forest. So, you don't need a duplicate function.

I think you overcomplicate things: if you reach the end of the path, we simply are done. So we can do this in one function:
insertPath :: Eq a => [a] -> [Tree a] -> [Tree a]
insertPath [] = id
insertPath (p : ps) = go
  where
    go [] = [Node p (insertPath ps [])]
    go (n@(Node x xs) : ns)
      | p == x = Node x (insertPath ps xs) : ns
      | otherwise = n : go ns
You can then generate the entire forest with a list of paths with:
insertPaths :: Eq a => [Tree a] -> [[a]] -> [Tree a]
insertPaths = foldl (flip insertPath)
With the sample data, we thus generate a forest with:
ghci> insertPaths [] [["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "b", "e"], ["f", "g"]]
[Node {rootLabel = "a", subForest = [Node {rootLabel = "b", subForest = [Node {rootLabel = "c", subForest = []},Node {rootLabel = "e", subForest = []}]}]},Node {rootLabel = "f", subForest = [Node {rootLabel = "g", subForest = []}]}]


I confess that I am a bit lost about the fact that you are defining a local go definition, but using insertPath inside go definition and using bound variables p and ps inside that local definition. Could you please explain ?

insertPath and go implement iteration over two different things: insertPath iterates over the path, while go iterates over the list of trees that each have the path added to them. go uses the same path for each tree, so it doesn't need to be parameterized on the path (i.e., you don't have to pass the path explicitly to each recursive call to go.)

I.e., go :: [Tree a] -> [Tree a], with an implicit path that gets used to update each tree in the input.

Thank you so much @chepner. It's difficult for me to see how is this function going to be evaluated. The base case of insertPath is clear; however, the recursive case is simply go. How would you think about the behavior of this function ?

Note that insertPath has type [a] -> [Tree a] -> [Tree a]. Normally, you think of it as a function that takes two arguments and returns a list of trees. Instead, think of it as a function that takes one argument and returns a function of type [Tree a] -> [Tree a]; that function is go.
